# Windows 8, moving recovery partition to a new USB drive

Tags: windows-8, microsoft-surface-pro, recovery-partition

I bought a Surface Pro 3 and I moved the recovery partition to a USB flash drive, using the built-in Windows 8 tool.

I would like to free up that USB drive and install the recovery partition on another USB drive. Is that possible? The "create a recovery drive" tool in Windows 8 will not work, because I cannot copy the recovery partition to that drive anymore (which is understandable, it was removed from the Surface).

Comment: Aren't the files copied not moved when creating a recovery drive? Could you clone the whole USB?

Comment: They are moved altogether (if you choose that option); the idea being to open up some space on your Surface by erasing the recovery partition. Maybe cloning would be an option, but I do not know how to clone a bootable USB drive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since copying the files won't work, you can try to **clone** the USB drive to the other:

Let the USB drive with the recovery partition be **A**, the blank one be **B**.

1. [Download](http://www.osforensics.com/tools/write-usb-images.html) **ImageUSB** and extract it (Winrar etc).
2. Connect A and B to your computer and start ImageUSB.
3. First we want to make a complete image of your pen drive and save them on the system. Now select your pen drive from the list and then click on **Create from UFD** option.
4. Save it anywhere convenient (eg Desktop) and it will be saved it as .bin file on the system. Finally, click on **Create image**.
5. Once it's done, select B and click **Write to UFD.**

Now that it's done, **remember to check if B is working!**

[Read more here.](http://www.techfeb.com/how-to-clone-bootable-pen-drive-to-another-one-tutorial-and-uses/)

Other methods to clone a USB [here](http://www.brighthub.com/computing/hardware/articles/72524.aspx).